# IFTTT recipe similar to zapier webhook

Tags: api, endpoint, zapier, ifttt

Does IFTTT has similar recipe to Zapier Webhook, to pool API Endpoint?

[Zapier Webhook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFurl.png)

Answer (score 1):

Sure, try the [Maker channel](https://ifttt.com/maker) for capturing webhook data.

Comment: But it waits on trigger, Zapier polls a URL every 15 minutes

Comment: Is there any specific reasons why you want to use polling instead of trigger? If you can explain a bit more, it is easier to help.